# Is it correct to physically remove a PCI-E device after 'removing' it via sysfs?

Tags: network-interface, hardware, pci, sysfs

Sometimes I have to replace a PCI Express device, for example a network card (NIC) on a Linux server. I was always wondering if it is possible to do without downtime.
I had success with **adding** new devices to a running system, involving writing "1" to `/sys/bus/pci/rescan`.
But I have never removed a device from a running system, because some articles are saying that it can harm hardware.
I'm able to write "1" to `/sys/bus/pci/devices/X:X:X:X/remove` on a specific device (after dropping it's usage count to 0).
But is it safe and correct to physically remove the device afterwards? Do PCI-E specifications define anything on that subject? Can it cause damage to hardware, or a kernel crash?
The answers I found on the internet are contradictory.
Does it depend on hardware?
I'm not using a special server-only hardware, my motherboard is from a desktop.
Have anyone had experience with removing PCI-E devices from a running system?

Comment: The hardware must support it (mainboard and the PCI-E card). The OS/driver need to support it. Take note that operating on a live powered electrical system is dangerously and life threatening and should only be done by an electrician, who is also an IT specialist. You'll most likely void guarantee and any insurance if doing otherwise. You might also lose your life or at least one of your limbs. So ask yourself, is it really worth?

Comment: @paladin electrical engineer here. Voltages inside modern computers are safe. Don't frighten the kids. You don't need an electrician to service computers. That's simply not true; otherwise a lot of data centers would have a lot of problems.

Comment: Only under normal circumstances, otherwise these might be the last words. Someone who's not an electrician cannot say to 100% that a system is operating under normal circumstances or not. Maybe you've 99% luck, but 1% bad luck, so from 100 computer systems, 1 kills you.

Comment: @paladin you're making things sound way more dangerous than they are; in fact, I think you're making things up. Again, I'm an electrical engineer. If you can explain to me the accident under which anyone could use a limb taking a PCIe device from a server, I will happily explain to you the safety measures that mitigate that possibility. Note that servers are *designed* with PCIe hotplug in mind. Would be pretty stupid if that wasn't safely possible.

Comment: Operator has wet and thin skin, touches 2 live electrical parts and dies by an heart attack. As an electrician you should know, not voltage kills you, current does.

Comment: @paladin there's no exposed medium voltages in a server, so wet operators can't touch anything. Even as an amateur you should know that current only flows where there's sufficient voltage.

Comment: You think that all machines are 100% made bulletproof and nothing can be damaged? I've some bad news. Your advise is irresponsible. Don't touch a live electrical system if you are not an electrician. Doing otherwise is like playing russian roulette. As you can see, even some electricians don't see the dangers which can come from an electrical machine. PS https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/girl-16-electrocuted-death-bath-29887697

Comment: Why do you only say that about the inside of a PC but not about e.g. the outside expansion ports such as USB, when they're also part of the exact same live electrical system?

Comment: @paladin no offense, I studied that stuff, and you cite *The Daily Mirror*, a tabloid mostly known for tits and lies. It gets details wrong - no surprise, the Mirror's tabloid press of the worst kind, and will always aim for maximum shock value. The death is tragic. Her charger fell into the water. When you take your server's power supply into the bath, the same could happen to you. But you don't. You would, worst case, touch things on the safe side of an isolated power supply, at voltages of at most 12 V. Exactly as u1686_grawity says, this is no more dangerous than plugging in a USB device.